# My two coffee files interfering with each other in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

The problem here is that in my rails app, I write 2 coffee script files both require window.onscroll fn.

When I implement them one at a time both works fine, but when I include both,
the script stops working.

Here is the first script

```
rightBarControl = ->
  windowHeight = $(window).height()
  scrollHeight = $(window).scrollTop()
  rightBarWidth = $('#index_top_confession_div').width()
  #20% of .main width
  rightBarHeight = $('#index_top_confession_div').outerHeight()
  rightBarOffset = $('#index_confessions').offset().left + $('#index_confessions').outerWidth()
  rightBarTop = 75
  #30 because .head is 30px high
  if windowHeight - 75 < rightBarHeight
    #Again including 30 because of .head
    rightBarTop = windowHeight - rightBarHeight
  if windowHeight + scrollHeight - 75 >= rightBarHeight
    $('#index_top_confession_div').css
      position: 'fixed'
      left: rightBarOffset
      top: rightBarTop
  else
    $('#index_top_confession_div').css
      position: 'static'
      left: rightBarOffset
      top: rightBarTop
  return

$('#search').addClass 'form-control'
$(window).scroll rightBarControl
#Run control on window scroll
$(window).resize rightBarControl
```

The second script file..

```
 $(document).ready ->
  if $('.pagination').length
    $(window).scroll ->
      console.log('hey');
      url = undefined
      url = $('.pagination .next_page').attr('href')
      if url and $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 200
        $('.pagination').html '<img src = \'/uploads/loader/loader.gif\' alt=\'loading...\'/>'
        return $.getScript(url)
      return
    return $(window).scroll()
  return
```

Answer (score 0):

Asset Pipeline combines all the CSS and Javascript files into one big file.

When you have `$(window).scroll()` in both coffeescript files, both functions will run.

There are few ways around this. One is to edit your `layout.html.erb` to have a controller name as a body `class` or `id`. Then you can check for it in your coffeescript to run the correct js on the correct page

Another way is to make sure you always target the elements by the `id` or `class`, not avoid using website wide targets like `body` or `window`

Comment: umm.. the point is both run on the same page.. one control the rightbar and one control the infinite scrolling